# Flink - How to combine process time and count trigger?

Tags: apache-flink

I have a Flink streaming job, where I am creating windows based on some keys and adding the data points to a data point.

```
.window(SlidingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.days(1), Time.minutes(5)))
.trigger(CountTrigger.of(5))
.window(<ProcessWindowFunction>)
```

I'm using the above piece of code for creating sliding window of size 1 day with a slide of 5 minutes. Als, count trigger is triggering the process function once 5 data points are accumulated.

In addition to this, I want to trigger the process function for every `slide` that happens. This means, till 1 day of data points are accumulated (`window size`), `CountTrigger` shall trigger the `process` function and once 1 day worth points are created and window slides for every 5 minutes, I want to trigger the process function for every data point instead of waiting for `CountTrigger` to accumulate 10 data points. Can someone please help me on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that this is going to be pretty painful. Every event is going to be assigned to a total of 288 windows (24 hours / 5 minutes). This means that every event is going to trigger 288 calls to your ProcessWindowFunction.

If you find you need to optimize this, you can probably get better performance with a carefully implemented KeyedProcessFunction.

Comment: Thanks for your response @David. This is where I'm struggling to think of a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Extend `org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.triggers.CountTrigger` and override `onProcessingTime` method. Implement your processing time logic there. Then use this trigger instead of plain `CountTrigger`.

Comment: Thanks @bottaio for your reply. I'll check that.